# Angular 5 datatables not making ajax call

Tags: angular5, angular-datatables

The ajax request is never fired and doesn't show in console network as well. How could I use ajax properly ?

```
this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        autoWidth: true,
        order: [],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {

            that.loadTransactionTypeDetailsList(dataTablesParameters, this.selectedServiceTransaction, reportTime, function (res) {
                that.sTDList = res.data;
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: res.recordsTotal,
                    recordsFiltered: res.recordsFiltered,
                    data: res.data
                });
            });
        },
        columns: [{ data: '' }]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented datatable serverside in angular5.
I am able to make ajax request successfully.
I think you are passing these two parameters ( this.selectedServiceTransaction, reportTime,)  along with post request which prevent you to make ajax request.

```
this.dtOptions = {
          pagingType: 'full_numbers',
          pageLength: 10,
          serverSide: true,
          processing: true,
          ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
            this.dataService.GetValue(dataTablesParameters).then(function (res) {
              this.GetList= res.obj.data;

              callback({
                recordsTotal: res.obj.recordsTotal,
                recordsFiltered: res.obj.recordsFiltered,
                data: [],
              })
            }.bind(this), err => { });
          },

          columns: [
            { data: 'Id' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'PhoneNumber' },
            { data: 'Address' },
            { data: 'Email' },
            { data: 'Id', orderable: false }
          ]
        };
```